# Android app to anonymize a JPG picture but leave latitude/longitude and time

Tags: android, open-source, image-processing, privacy, exif

Before uploading a JPG picture to a public website, I want to remove any metadata that could help identify me. The only things I want left are:

- Latitude/Longitude where the picture was taken
- Date/Time when the picture was taken
- Image orientation
- The image itself, of course

All of the rest should be deleted. In particular:

- Camera serial number
- Camera manufacturer/model/resolution/software/serial number
- Camera settings such flash/ISO/shutter/focal/quality
- File name should be randomized

Further requirements:

- The original file should not be overwritten.
- Ideally I should be able to immediately "share" the picture to another app.
- Open source.

What I tried:

- [ObscuraCam](https://guardianproject.info/apps/obscuracam): Unfortunately deletes the GPS latitude/longitude.

Comment: Not sure if any of those fits (I don't do photo editing on Android myself), but it might be worth checking with my little list of [Android Exif editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_1044) ;)

Comment: @Izzy: The nearest in your list would be EZ UnEXIF Free, which unfortunately removes latitude/longitude and is not open source.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that. Nothing to do about open-sourcing it; for the other part, maybe the dev is willing to add a feature. Apart from that, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

SendReduced is an [open-source](https://github.com/arpruss/sendreduced), *or paid for the [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.SendReduced_pro)*, Android app that allows you to:

- Original file is **not** overwritten.
- Set the maximum resolution that you wish to send photos to another destination
- Select Multiple Images to "Send"
- Reduced Files can be given a name can be a simple sequential number, random number, etc.
- You can select which application you would like to "Send" the files with and optionally make this selection sticky.
- Strip All *free version* or Selected *Pro Version* EXIF information
- In the pro version, *currently £0.80 here*, you have the option of including or excluding:

  - GPS Location
  - Settings
  - Make/Model
  - Timestamp

[image][image][image][image][image]